# How to recover from a terminated pulsar bookie

Tags: apache-pulsar, apache-bookkeeper

We are running Apache Pulsar 2.72. in Prod which uses a 5 node (aws r5ad.2xlarge) bookie cluster (4.12.0). One of the nodes was terminated. As per our ASG a new node came up and joined the cluster.
The Bookies have

1. autoRecoveryDaemonEnabled=true
2. lostBookieRecoveryDelay=0
3. bookkeeperClientMinNumRacksPerWriteQuorum=2
4. managedLedgerDefaultEnsembleSize=3
5. managedLedgerDefaultWriteQuorum=3

However the ledger re-replication wasn't taking place. I tried decommissioning the terminated node using sudo /opt/apache-pulsar/apache-pulsar-2.7.2/bin/bookkeeper shell decommissionbookie -bookieid bookieIP:port  but it was stuck at
23:53:36.465 [main] INFO  org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdmin - Count of Ledgers which need to be rereplicated: 793
00:03:37.293 [main] INFO  org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdmin - Count of Ledgers which need to be rereplicated: 793
00:13:38.119 [main] INFO  org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdmin - Count of Ledgers which need to be rereplicated: 793
00:23:39.194 [main] INFO  org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdmin - Count of Ledgers which need to be rereplicated: 793
00:33:39.995 [main] INFO  org.apache.bookkeeper.client.BookKeeperAdmin - Count of Ledgers which need to be rereplicated: 793
for more than 30 mins. We even tried getting the ledgers which were underreplicated using sh bookkeeper shell listunderreplicated and read some of the returned ledgers using sh bookkeeper shell ledger -m  but that failed with an exception complaining about unable to access terminated bookie. We ended up deleting the underreplicated ledgers.

I am looking for a suggestion to best recover from a terminated bookie with our having to delete ledgers

Comment: I've seen a bug that results in null ledgers that seem to get stuck and stay under replicated, but I'm not sure if it's been reported yet. Next time it happens, please update your post with example ledger and entry IDs. For legitimate ledgers, we've never had a problem with them failing to replicate.

Answer (score -1):

Now that Apache Pulsar 2.8.1 is out, can you upgrade and try again.   It seems unusual.

To get access to all the Pulsar people in one location, sign up for the summit

https://streamnative.io/en/blog/community/2021-09-07-speakers-announced-for-pulsar-virtual-summit-europe-2021/